# Save parameters parsed by JCommander to file

Tags: java, jcommander

Is it possible in [JCommander](http://jcommander.org/) to save class annotated with `jcommander.Parameter` to file, so one could create new object, using [@ syntax](http://jcommander.org/#Syntax) to read from file?

For example, if I have annotated class

```
class IndexerCommandLineParameters {
    @Parameter(names = { "-s", "--source" }, description = "Source file or directory of audio files (*.wav or *.mp3). MUST BE 16bit!", required=true)
    public String source;

    @Parameter(names = { "-d", "--destination" }, description = "Destination file or directory (type must match source type).", required=true)
    public String destination;

    @Parameter(names = { "-v", "--verbositiy" }, description = "Verbosity in stderr: 0 - print only file processing errors, 1 - print indexing progress")
    public int verbositiy=1;

    @Parameter(names = {"-f", "--force"}, description = "Force to reindex alredy indexed fiels")
    public boolean reindex = true;

    @Parameter(names = {"-h", "--help"}, description = "Force to reindex alredy indexed fiels", help = true)
    private boolean help;
}
```

And class initialization

```
IndexerCommandLineParameters p = new IndexerCommandLineParameters();
JCommander c=new JCommander(p);
c.parse("-s", "xxxxx","-d", "yyyyy");
p.verbositiy=2;
```

I want to create file, that contains something like

```
-s xxxxx -d yyyyy -v 3 -f
```

I know I can create `.toString()` or something similar in each class, but I was looking for something more general, where I don't have to add some code to each annotated class.